Unable to access UI of Apache Jena Fuseki 2 on Windows 10
I'm trying to work with a newly installed local instance of Apache Jena Fuseki v 5.2.0 on Windows 10.
It's successfully installed, and I launch the server from the command line with the most basic configuration possible, like this:
c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0> fuseki-server --loc=L:\data /mydataset
The console replies:
c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0>fuseki-server --loc=L:\data /mydataset
15:15:20 INFO  Server          :: Running in read-only mode for /mydataset
15:15:20 INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 5.2.0
15:15:20 WARN  ServletContextHandler :: BaseResource file:///c:/java/apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0/webapp/ is aliased to file:///C:/java/apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0/webapp/ in oeje10w.WebAppContext@3249a1ce{org.apache.jena.fuseki.Servlet,/,b=file:///c:/java/apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0/webapp/,a=STOPPED,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@4dd94a58{STOPPED}}. May not be supported in future releases.
15:15:20 WARN  ContextHandler  :: Base Resource should not be an alias (100% of requests to context are subject to Security/Alias Checks): file:///c:/java/apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0/webapp/ points to file:///C:/java/apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0/webapp/
15:15:20 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_HOME=c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0\.
15:15:20 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_BASE=c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0\run
15:15:20 INFO  Config          :: Shiro file: file://c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0\run\shiro.ini
15:15:20 INFO  Config          :: Template file: templates/config-tdb2-dir-readonly
15:15:21 INFO  Server          :: Database: TDB2 dataset: location=L:\data
15:15:21 INFO  Server          :: Path = /mydataset
15:15:21 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 1.2 GiB
15:15:21 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   21.0.4
15:15:21 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Windows 10 10.0 amd64
15:15:21 INFO  Server          ::   PID:    25904
15:15:21 INFO  Server          :: Started 2024/12/12 15:15:21 PST on port 3030

Then, I attempt to access the UI using the URL provided in the Fuseki Quickstart document:
http://localhost:3030//query.html
To which the response is:
HTTP ERROR 400 Ambiguous URI empty segment
URI:    /badURI
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE:    Ambiguous URI empty segment

If I call the default URI, as in http://localhost:3030/:
I get a 404:
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    http://localhost:3030/
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found

So, the server is obviously accessible from my browser (Chrome 131.0.6778.139). If I request http://localhost:3030/$/ping, a current datetime stamp is returned. All of the other admin URLs, documented at https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html appear to return a simple text or JSON response. Similarly, a call to: http://localhost:3030/mydataset/query returns:
Service Description: /mydataset/query

So, clearly, the Fuseki server is answering HTTP requests. But for some reason, I cannot raise the GUI, and more importantly, the SPARQL endpoint, which I expect to see.
Might anyone have any insight on why I cannot raise the Fuseki UI?
Many thanks in advance.

The URL http://localhost:3030/ should work; The ServletContextHandler warning may be related.  Are any of the path components of FUSEKI_BASE file system links?

The URL for the Query UI will be http://localhost:3030/#/dataset/mydataset/query, not http://localhost:3030/query.html. http://localhost:3030/mydataset/query is the SPARQL endpoint, not UI. It requires a query string ?query=.

Hi @AndyS. No, there are no links in the FUSEKI_BASE path, i.e., c:\java\apache-jena-fuseki-5.2.0. And accessing http://localhost:3030/#/dataset/mydataset/query returns  404 in the browser, but the console does not register the request or the response in its log messages

Then the only oddity showing is the path having "C:". Could you try  FUSEKI_HOME=C:\java\... and also with the file:///C:/java/... as reported by ServletContextHandler (which is Jetty code).
